# Facebook auto-login JS works in console but not in GM script

Tags: javascript, facebook, greasemonkey, autologin

I am trying to create an auto login script for Facebook rather than use a preexisting one. When I run the following code in the javascript console of both Firefox and Chrome both the username and password fields are filled out as expected:

```
var username = "myemail@email.com";
var password = "password";
var f = document.getElementById("login_form");
f.elements.namedItem("email").value = username;
f.elements.namedItem("pass").value = password;
```

but when I run it as a Greasemonkey script they don't fill out:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Auto Login for FB
// @namespace      hamsolo474
// @description    AutoLogin 
// @include        https://www.facebook.com
// ==/UserScript==
var username = "myemail@email.com";
var password = "password";
var f = document.getElementById("login_form");
f.elements.namedItem("email").value = username;
f.elements.namedItem("pass").value = password;
```

I read through [this link](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Greasemonkey_Hacks/Getting_Started#Pitfall_.233%3a_Named_Forms_and_Form_Elements) but that didn't seem to help. This is a derivative of a GM script that I run successfully on other websites, I don't understand why its not working here, any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

**EDIT:**
I have also tried an alternate method of:

```
var username = "myemail@email.com";
var password = "password";
document.getElementsByName("email", "input")[0].value = username;
document.getElementsByName("pass", "input")[0].value = password;
```

as the javascript and:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Auto Login for FB
// @namespace      hamsolo474
// @description    AutoLogin 
// @include        https://www.facebook.com
// ==/UserScript==
var username = "myemail@email.com";
var password = "password";
document.getElementsByName("email", "input")[0].value = username;
document.getElementsByName("pass", "input")[0].value = password;
```

as the GM, much like my first method it works in the JS console for both Firefox and Chrome, but not in GM for either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be that the `@include` directive is not set correctly.  Use:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Auto Login for FB
// @namespace      hamsolo474
// @description    AutoLogin 
// @include        http://www.facebook.com/*
// @include        https://www.facebook.com/*
// ==/UserScript==
var username = "myemail@email.com";
var password = "password";
var f = document.getElementById("login_form");
f.elements.namedItem("email").value = username;
f.elements.namedItem("pass").value = password;
```

---

**However:**  It is always a bad idea to embed account information in *any* code file.

If you just want to make it easier to get into your Facebook account, you'd be better off, and safer, using [the *Secure Login* add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/secure-login/).

Comment: thanks that did the job, yeah I am just learning how to use greasemonkey. Understanding why my code wasn't working is more important to me than logging into fb slightly faster, thank you for the help, it is odd that the asterisk is needed when I don't see the URL change